# Entity framework, What is the difference between AsNoTracking and MergeOption = NoTracking?

Tags: entity-framework

**What is the difference between**
`MyEntities.AsNoTracking()` **and** `context.MyEntities.MergeOption = MergeOption.NoTracking;`**?**

I took the merge option thing from the second recommandation [here](https://rahulgbhatia.wordpress.com/2013/03/12/tips-to-improve-entity-framework-performance/), but I have yet to find it for real. I suspect the "MergeOption" thing was removed by Microsoft since then.

Comment: What version of EntityFramework are you using? MergeOption is used on ObjectSets/ObjectContext. Since 4.1 onwards, DbContext sits on top of ObjectContext and AsNoTracking is present.

Comment: @thudbutt I use 6.1.3, so my guess was right. They are the same thing?

Comment: Yes, under the covers AsNoTracking uses MergeOption.NoTracking. Will add details to my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AsNoTracking is simply the DbContext/DbSet version (EF 4.1 onwards) of the MergeOption.NoTracking ObjectContext/ObjectSet version (EF 4 and below).

AsNoTracking implementation:

```
public static IQueryable AsNoTracking(this IQueryable source)
        {
            Check.NotNull(source, "source");

            var asDbQuery = source as DbQuery;
            return asDbQuery != null ? asDbQuery.AsNoTracking() : CommonAsNoTracking(source);
        }
```

CommonAsNoTracking implementation:

```
private static T CommonAsNoTracking<T>(T source) where T : class
        {
            DebugCheck.NotNull(source);

            var asObjectQuery = source as ObjectQuery;
            if (asObjectQuery != null)
            {
                return (T)DbHelpers.CreateNoTrackingQuery(asObjectQuery);
            }

            var noTrackingMethod = source.GetType().GetPublicInstanceMethod("AsNoTracking");
            if (noTrackingMethod != null
                && typeof(T).IsAssignableFrom(noTrackingMethod.ReturnType))
            {
                return (T)noTrackingMethod.Invoke(source, null);
            }

            return source;
        }
```

CreateNoTrackingQuery implementation:

```
public static IQueryable CreateNoTrackingQuery(ObjectQuery query)
        {
            DebugCheck.NotNull(query);

            var asIQueryable = (IQueryable)query;
            var newQuery = (ObjectQuery)asIQueryable.Provider.CreateQuery(asIQueryable.Expression);
            newQuery.ExecutionStrategy = query.ExecutionStrategy;
            newQuery.MergeOption = MergeOption.NoTracking;
            newQuery.Streaming = query.Streaming;
            return newQuery;
        }
```

Taken from https://entityframework.codeplex.com